# How to make jconsole connect to a helidon jvm?

Tags: jconsole, helidon

I am trying to use jconsole to retrieve some quick performance attributes of a running helidon app (4.0.0-M1 Helidon-MP). However I am not able to connect to the jvm. However jconsole is able to connect to other jvms.

I tried runing jconsole in administrator mode, but to no avail. What do I have to do to enable jconsole connections to Helidon apps?

Answer (score 3):

this can be fixed as follows:

- add `src/main/resources/META-INF/helidon/serial-config.properties` file with
  `pattern=javax.management.**;java.lang.**;java.rmi.**;javax.security.auth.Subject`
- or add the following system property: `-Dhelidon.serialFilter.pattern=javax.management.**;java.lang.**;java.rmi.**;javax.security.auth.Subject;!*`

Helidon enforces JEP-290 by disabling ALL deserialization. If a components or application requires it, is must be explicitly enabled. Please check class `io.helidon.common.SerializationConfig` that is responsible for this.